# Xlib equivalent to QPainter::translate

Tags: qt, user-interface, coordinates, xlib, coordinate-transformation

How can I use xlib functions to implement QPainter::translate functionality.
I want xlib to add some xOffset, yOffset to all pixels when it draws.

I can keep tow variables xOffset and yOffset and add them to drawing functions every they are called. But I want to do it once like QPainter::translate.